# How to define the direction perpendicular to a GameObject's motion (Unity)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector, 2d

I'm trying to create a game where a ball is launched off from a circle, much like a cannon, but it can be launched into any direction, 360º because the circle which the ball is attached to can rotate. So, I was thinking of using Rigidbody2D.AddForce() but I'm not sure how to define the direction I want the force to be applied. I want it to be the direction perpendicular to the ball/player's movement but I don't know how to define that. Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

If you get the direction that the ball is travelling (as say degrees) you can add a certain angle to that and use the angle to determine the force that needs to be applied.

I'm assuming that the ball/player has no ridged body, if it does then you can just grab the direction directly. Also since your using circle to describe the spawned shape i'm going to assume your working in 2D.

```
Vector3 lastPosition;

void Update()
{
    //launch the ball before updating the last position
    lastPosition = transform.position;
}

Vector3 launchDirection()
{
    Vector3 ballDirection = transform.position - lastPosition;
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(ballDirection.x, ballDirection.y) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

    //the direction should be perpendicular to direction of movement
    float angle += 90;

    return new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(angle), Mathf.Sin(angle));
}
```

I haven't ran the code in unity but it looks like it should work. Basically to get the direction you store the last position and compare it to the current direction to work out the delta (if your using a ridged body to move around then grab the direction from that instead) then use atan2 to get the angle. To make the launch direction perpendicular to the ball I added 90 degrees (you might want -90 depending on what side you need the circle to launch from). Now that we have the angle that you want the ball to shoot out from, use that with Sin and Cos to get the XY of the angle.

There you have it that will get you the direction perpendicular to movement, you your using 3 dimensions it's basically the same maths just with a few numbers thrown in to pad the return value.

Oh if your object always faces the direction of movement `transform.right` also works :P